# sage: problems with product of vector of symbols with square matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, product, symbolic-math, sage

I am trying to do some experiments with symbols (variable vector) and multiplications with a coefficient matrix.

The code is the following:

```
A = matrix(QQ,[
    [2,1,2,-6],
    [-1,2,1,7],
    [3,-1,-3,-1],
    [1,5,6,0]
])

k = A.transpose().kernel()
basis = k.basis()[0]
t = 'real'
var('x1')
assume(x1,t)
var('x2')
assume(x2,t)
var('x3')
assume(x3,t)
var('x4')
assume(x4,t)

x = vector([x1,x2,x3,x4])
print "x",x
xT = x.transpose()
print "xT",xT
print "A*x",A*x
print "xT*A",xT*A
```

with the following output:

```
x (x1, x2, x3, x4)
xT [x1]
[x2]
[x3]
[x4]
A*x (2*x1 + x2 + 2*x3 - 6*x4, -x1 + 2*x2 + x3 + 7*x4, 3*x1 - x2 - 3*x3 - x4, x1 + 5*x2 + 6*x3)
xT*A
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/tmpuVBZ96/___code___.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec compile(u'print "xT*A",xT*A
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "element.pyx", line 2751, in sage.structure.element.Matrix.__mul__ (sage/structure/element.c:19587)
  File "coerce.pyx", line 856, in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel_cache_maps.bin_op (sage/structure    /coerce.c:8169)
TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for '*': 'Full MatrixSpace of 4 by 1 dense matrices over Symbolic Ring'     and 'Full MatrixSpace of 4 by 4 dense matrices over Rational Field'
```

As you can see, `A*x` was successful, but `xT*A` is giving an exception. Do you have any idea on why? How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know sage and don't have it installed, but this is similar to a matlab issue so I'll just make a couple of suggestions until an expert comes along.  I don't think vectors are particularly rows or columns.  Try just using x*A instead of xT*A, I think sage allows that.  To test, compare against A.transpose()*x.